# SSRS Migration 2008 to 2014 - InternalCatalogException secDesc != null

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2014

We're migrating side by side from SSRS 2008 Web to SSRS 2014 Enterprise. I followed the steps - backup encryption key, backup databases (ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB), restored databases, restore the encryption key and finally  pointed SSRS to use the database. All went fine, however I'm getting an error whenever I try to fire up ReportManager http://server/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx

> library!ReportServer_0-2!588!09/01/2015-17:33:44:: i INFO: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False).
>
> library!ReportServer_0-2!588!09/01/2015-17:33:44:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.**InternalCatalogException: secDesc != null**, Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details.;

Something else to mention, this database was initially on SSRS 2005 Standard, then migrated to SSRS 2008 Web via the same steps i`ve described above.

Any ideas what I could try to make it work ?

If more info is needed, I can provide it.

Comment: any solution here?  I am having the same issue

Comment: One thing i found was a trigger/procedure referencing incorrect ReportServerTempDB. But even after fixing that, it didn't work and i had to migrate all my reports / datasources from one server to another - there are a few tools out there - ReportSync is one of them, but you might need to change some code if you're using forms authentication on one of the servers.

Comment: Thank you sir.  I do figure that will be the eventual outcome for me as well.